# How to enter the seconds in lightning input date-time

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I don't know how to enter seconds as well in the date-time field because of lightning input takes only hours and minutes

```
<lightning:input type="datetime" name="input1" label="Enter a date/time value" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard tag in lightning which takes seconds also. You will have to be creative and create you own tag.

Use combination of these -

**Component Code: youComponent.cmp** - Add this in your component

```
<aura:attribute name="dateTime" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="seconds" type="Integer"/>
 <lightning:card title="Date/Time with seconds picker">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-m-around_small">
        <div class="slds-col"><lightning:input type="datetime" name="input1" label="Date/Time" value="{!v.dateTime}"/></div>
        <div class="slds-col"><lightning:input type="number" name="input1" label="Seconds" class="seconds" max="59" min="1" value="{!v.seconds}"/></div>
    </div>
    <aura:set attribute="footer">
        <!-- This button is to show the time with seconds, you do not need to have this, as you will have you own events-->
        <lightning:button label="Show Time" onclick="{!c.showTime}"/>
    </aura:set>
</lightning:card>
```

**Controller.js - to get the final Date with seconds**

```
showTime : function(component, event, helper){
    var dateTime = component.get("v.dateTime");
    var seconds = component.get("v.seconds");

    var d = new Date(dateTime);

    var finalDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() , d.getDate() , d.getHours() , d.getMinutes() , seconds , 0);

    //convert the finalDate to ISOString as salesforce returns the same from DateTime component.
    console.log("New Data = " + finalDate.toISOString());
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use lightning:formattedDateTime tag to achieve this

```
 <lightning:formattedDateTime value="1479944705000" hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit" second="2-digit" hour12="false" timeZoneName="long"/>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedDateTime/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleTimeFormatting

Comment: He is asking for input, formattedDateTime is just to display dataTime value

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to enter the seconds, not to display